# Using xlsxwriter, Excel file cannot be opened. File extension is not valid

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlsxwriter

I am trying to insert a macro when creating an Excel file using xlsxwriter library. I followed the tutorial example from the documentation: [Working with VBA Macros](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html).

The file was created but when attempting to open with Microsoft Excel, it prompted the following message :

> Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

**Note:**

1. I am using Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (12.0.6425.1000) SP2 MSO version on Windows 10.
2. Opening with LibreOffice is fine but click the button is not responding anything (since it cannot read VBA).

```py
def action_macro_test(self):
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("/home/user1/Desktop/macro_test.xlsm")
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet1")

        worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

        # Add the VBA project binary.
        workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')

        # Show text for the end user.
        worksheet.write('A3', 'Press the button to say hello.')

        # Add a button tied to a macro in the VBA project.
        worksheet.insert_button('B3', {'macro':   'say_hello',
                                    'caption': 'Say Hello!',
                                    'width':   80,
                                    'height':  30})

        workbook.close()
```

Comment: It always helps to post your actual code, instead of a link to a tutorial or other page.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, thanks for the suggestion, i have updated my question with the actual code

Answer (score 1):

You created a workbook with macros, but saved it as `.xlsx`. Excel does not allow macros in `.xlsx` files. They must be `.xlsm`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the thing is I have saved it as .xlsm as the documentation suggest, is there anything that I missed out ? Will update my post with the code snippet

Comment: I have updated my question with the actual code, i have used the '.xlsm' format but it is still showing that error message when open with Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code, with only the path modified, and it created a file that opened as expected:

```py
import xlsxwriter

def action_macro_test(self):
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("macro_test.xlsm")
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet1")

        worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

        # Add the VBA project binary.
        workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')

        # Show text for the end user.
        worksheet.write('A3', 'Press the button to say hello.')

        # Add a button tied to a macro in the VBA project.
        worksheet.insert_button('B3', {'macro':   'say_hello',
                                    'caption': 'Say Hello!',
                                    'width':   80,
                                    'height':  30})

        workbook.close()

action_macro_test(None)
```

**Output**:

[image]

I used the `vbaProject.bin` file that is in the examples directory of the XlsxWriter distro and I tested it with several different versions of Excel.

Can, you try the `macros.py` example in the examples directory of the distro and see if that works for you. After that ensure you have a valid `vbaProject.bin` file in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will test it again and update the result soon. May I know, @jmcnamara are you opening the file with LibreOffice or Microsoft Excel ?

Is there any pop up message when you click on the button "Say Hello"?

Comment: I am only using Excel, and the message does pop up.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the file vbaProject.bin path is not correctly set. It is working fine now. Sorry for the false alarm. thanks for the help.